# How to get all records that also "own" specific records performantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models in Rails application

```
class Students < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
  attr_accessor :name
end

class Courses < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :students
  attr_accessor :name, :course_id
end
```

I would like to get a a list of all courses shared for each student who has been in the same class as a selected student in an efficient manner.

Given the following students:

- `Jerry's courses ["math", "english", "spanish"]`,
- `Bob's courses ["math", "english", "french"]`,
- `Frank's courses ["math", "basketweaving"]`
- `Harry's courses ["basketweaving"]`

If the selected student was Jerry, I would like the following object returned

```
{ Bob: ["math", "english"], Frank: ["math"] }
```

I know this will be an expensive operation, but my gut tells me there's a better way than what I'm doing. Here's what I've tried:

```
# student with id:1 is selected student
courses = Student.find(1).courses

students_with_shared_classes = {}
courses.each do |course|
  students_in_course = Course.find(course.id).students
  students_in_course.each do |s|
    if students_with_shared_classes.key?(s.name)
      students_with_shared_classes[s.name].append(course.name)
    else
      students_with_shared_classes[s.name] = [course.name]
    end
  end
end
```

Are there any ActiveRecord or SQL tricks for a situation like this?

Comment: To start off you need to remove `attr_accessor` from your models as it clobbers the setters that ActiveRecord creates by reading your database schema. If you leave it in place your attributes will not be persisted in the database!

Comment: You also need a join model to create a many to many assocation. You can generate the model with `rails g model enrollment student:belongs_to course:belongs_to` and then setup the assocations as `has_many :students, through: :enrollments` and `has_many :courses, through: :enrollments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```rb
student_id = 1
courses = Student.find(student_id).courses

other_students = Student
  .join(:courses)
  .eager_load(:courses)
  .where(courses: courses)
  .not.where(id: student_id)
```

This would give a collection of other students that took `courses` with only two db queries, and then you'd need to narrow down to the collection you're trying to create:

```rb
course_names = courses.map(&:name)
other_students.each_with_object({}) do |other_student, collection|
  course_names = other_student.courses.map(&:name)
  collection[other_student.name] = course_names.select { |course_name| course_names.include?(course_name) }
end
```

The above would build out `collection` where the key is the student names, and the values are the array of courses that match what `student_id` took.

Comment: One problem with this is that  `other_student.courses` will create a N+1 query since the association is not eager loaded. If you add `.eager_load(:courses)` it should combine the INNER JOIN with an OUTER JOIN which eager loads courses as well in a single query. https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where

Answer (score 2):

Provided you setup a join model (as required unless you use `has_and_belongs_to_many`) you could query it directly and use an array aggregate:

```
# given the student 'jerry'
enrollments = Enrollment.joins(:course)
                        .joins(:student)
                        .select(
                          'students.name AS student_name',
                          'array_agg(courses.name) AS course_names'
                        )
                        .where(course_id: jerry.courses)
                        .where.not(student_id: jerry.id)
                        .group(:student_id)
```

[`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) is a Postgres specific function. On MySQL and I belive Oracle you can use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to the same end. SQLite only has `group_concat` which returns a comma separated string.

If you want to get a hash from there you can do:

```
enrollments.each_with_object({}) do |e, hash|
  hash[e.student_name] = e.course_names
end
```

This option is not as database independent as Gavin Millers excellent answer but does all the work on the database side so that you don't have to iterate through the records in ruby and sort out the courses that they don't have in common.